# Is there a polynomial which vanishes at only one point

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Assume $(a,b) \in \mathbb C^2$. Is there a polynomial $f(x,y)$ which vanishes only at $(a,b)$ ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the algebraic sledgehammer. If $V(f)$ is a point, $\sqrt{(f)}$ is a maximal ideal, which is a contradiction, since $(f)$ is always contained in a non-maximal prime ideal $(g)$, where $g$ is an irreducible factor of $f$.

Or you do it the more elementary way:

Without loss of generality assume $(a,b)=(0,0)$. For any $t \in \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ the polynomial $g(x) := f(x,t)$ has no root, hence is constant. The same holds for $f(t,y)$ and you can deduce that $f$ itself is constant from that.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. For any $f(x,y)$ which is not constant, we can view it as a polynomial of one variable $y$ with coefficients within the ring $\mathbb C[x]$. There are infinitely many values, and so some values of $x$ not equal to $a$, where none of the coefficients of $f(x,y)$ vanish. Then fix any of such value, and we get a polynomial $f(y)$ which is not constant and thus has a solution.

Answer (score -2):

No,

You are working on a plane, and one single equation $f(x,y)=0$ left you a 1-dimensional solutions subspace.

Comment: This answer is wrong. $f$ need not be linear. Over the reals,   $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ has one point as the solution set.

Comment: but in $\mathbb R^2$ the polynomial $x^2 + y^2 = 0$ is a single equation and it vanishes only at $(0,0)$. What is the difference ?

Comment: @Woodface It's over $\mathbb{C}^2$. So what about $f(1,i)=0$?

Comment: The difference is that now we are working on an algebraically closed field.

Comment: @Spenser I know the question is about $\mathbb C^2$, and the problem statement is true (I just pointed to a duplicate, btw). I'm explaining why the given argument is wrong.

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo There is nothing in your answer that uses the field being algebraically closed.

Comment: WLOG, we can assume it to be nonconstant in $x$, and then $f(x,y_{0})$ has at least one root for any $y_{0}\in\Bbb{C}$.